# PHP Session Doesn't Seem To Work

Tags: php, session

I am setting up AfterLogic Webmail Lite, which requires PHP with session support. It says that session support is not enabled, but I find this quite strange, since `session.save_handler` *is* defined:

```
session.save_handler = files
```

I tried setting this to `/tmp`, but that didn't work either. I installed PHP from the Arch repositories (not AUR). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `php -i` (or executing `phpinfo()` in a script) and check the following :

- is the `session` extension loaded ? (running `php -m|grep session` or executing `function_exists("session_start")` will also answer to this question)
- is session.auto_start enabled ?
- is session.save_path existing and writeable by the server process ?
- what is the software doing to be able to tell that session support is not enabled ?

Comment: function_exists("session_start") returns true, and php -m | grep session returns 'session'. This is really weird.

Comment: Then either the software is expecting `session.auto_start` to be enabled, or its check is wrong (finding out how the software is checking this might help)

Comment: Its worked in other places. And session.auto_start is set to 1.

Comment: Well, it seems that clicking 'Retry' instead of refreshing the page worked. Wow. Sorry for wasting your time.